# Add existing project from GitHub to my local Visual Studio Solution

Tags: git, visual-studio, github

I have a local Solution developed in Visual Studio. It is also published in GitHub (https://github.com/symasdesign/DiagramTest). Now I want to add another project from GitHub (https://github.com/symasdesign/stateless).

For this, I have added the project stateless as a submodule to DiagramTest with

```
...\DiagramTest>git submodule add https://github.com/symasdesign/stateless.git
```

The Solution `stateless.sln` is now added in a subdirectory to `...\DiagramTest`:

```
...\DiagramTest\stateless\Stateless.sln
```

It contains the project `Stateless.csproj` at

```
...\DiagramTest\stateless\src\Stateless\Stateless.csproj
```

When I add this project to my Solution `DiagramTest`, I get the following error in Visual Studio:

```
Assets file '...\DiagramTest\stateless\src\Stateless\obj\project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file.
```

When I run "Restore NuGet Packages" I get the error

```
Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: The operation failed as details for project Stateless could not be loaded.
```

What do I wrong for adding the foreign project to my solution and get it working?

Answer (score 0):

I get it working with run of

```
dotnet restore
```